# Xinput/libinput button remapping with Trackball scrolling

Tags: mouse, xinput, libinput

So I'm using my trackball and I have configured it with trackball scrolling. What I now want to do is to remap the original scroll wheel to be used for some different function. The Problem is that when remapping them, the Trackball scrolling also gets remapped to whatever function I mapped the buttons.

From my understanding this shouldn't happen, it should send the key events 4 5 6 7 regardless of what those original buttons did. Just like normal mouse buttons do when remapped.

What I've tried so far is to remap other buttons to the original functionality of the scroll wheel, like button 12 is now used for scrolling and remapped to 5, and then mapping the Trackball scrolling function to that button, but that also doesn't work. I've used evdev for that, since I couldn't find any information on how to remap trackball scrolling axis with libinput.

The configuration I've tried it with:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "ELECOM TrackBall Mouse HUGE TrackBall"
    MatchProduct    "ELECOM TrackBall Mouse HUGE TrackBall"
    MatchIsPointer  "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver          "evdev"
    Option          "SendCoreEvents" "true"

    Option "Buttons"            "12"
    Option "ButtonMapping"      "1 10 3 11 12 0 0 0 4 5 6 7"
    Option "EmulateWheel"       "true"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "3"
    Option "YAxisMapping"       "9 10"
    Option "XAxisMapping"       "11 12"

EndSection
```

How I would like my configuration to look like:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "ELECOM TrackBall Mouse HUGE TrackBall"
    MatchProduct "ELECOM TrackBall Mouse HUGE TrackBall"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 12 3 14 15 9 8 18 19 10 11 2"
    Option "Scrollmethod" "button"
    Option "ScrollButton" "2"
EndSection
```

Buttons should work like mapped before, but the scroll function of the trackball should always send keys 4, 5, 6 and 7 that are used for scrolling, regardless of what the keys that originally had that function are mapped to.

Maybe there is a setting I missed or something else I forgot but I couldn't find anything anywhere regarding this after a few hours of trying.

Would appreciate any help or hints to the right sources.